# How to change the position of text in the Label widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I want to add a title on the background image, the code is

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
photo = PhotoImage(file = 'a.gif')
Label(root,text='Life is short \n you need python',image=photo, fg = 'red',\
  compound = CENTER,font = ('Times Newman',20)).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

get this
[CODE result shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsJct.png)

But I cannot change the position of text, I want to move the text to the top, like the arrow marked in the image.

Thanks, HELP!

Comment: Have you read the documentation on the `pack` command? It accepts many options. Have you tried them?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your attention, I post my answer. I have tried all the parameters of Label and pack, but didnot work, because the parameters are set to move all the label but the text, except the "font" parameter.
SO if you want to move the text on a Label with a background image, while the "compound" is set to "CENTER", the CODE should be rewritten as

```
from tkinter import *
txt = 'Life is short \n you need python \n\n\n\n\n' # just add some \n
root = Tk()
photo = PhotoImage(file = 'a.gif')
Label(root,text=txt,image=photo, fg = 'red',compound = CENTER,font = ('Times Newman',20)).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

[NEW CODE results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzQuN.png)